# Multiple where clauses in a search query (oracle) : Efficiency

Tags: performance, oracle

What is more efficient ?

1. Multiple where clauses in a single sql statement (no joins), NO
   INDICES on any columns?
2. Multiple where clauses in a single sql
   statement (no joins), INDICES on all columns with potential where
   clauses?
3. Dynamic SQL with build as you need where clauses.

Answer (score 1):

It's *very* hard to say without seeing the queries and the execution plans... but instinctively, I'd say that #2 is probably usually going to be the most efficient. An index will make it much easier for Oracle to find data in your table. Of course, over-indexing could cause performance problems as well.

I'm not sure that dynamic queries and indices have anything to do with each other. If your table has an index, a query (dynamic or not) will be able to use the index.

Comment: I am writing code to perform some search(es) (both simple and complex) from a front-end. Tradition suggests me to use dynamic queries...but the lack of compilation, and less debugging is forcing me to explore other options.

Comment: I'm very curious what tradition it is that's suggesting you to use dynamic queries... For me, dynamic queries are a last resort, when I can't do it any other way. Are you actually building the queries at run-time?

Comment: Here is a situation : I want to search a bunch of users from one or more tables. I dont want to put too many search conditions unless required...even though my search fields are pretty set. If they are empty, no point searching on them.

Comment: @Sash: So maybe dynamic SQL is the way to go here? I'm not sure what your architecture is like... I'd still think about indexing commonly searched fields (if you can determine which those are), as long as you're not indexing 500-character free-form text (that might not help at all), or maybe look into full-text search and indexing. If any of them are foreign keys or enum-like values, they might be good candidates for indexing.